# Java preg_match between brackets

Tags: java, regex

in my application i can use this string:

```
String test = "hello" + "[" + 800 + "]" + "\n" + "world" + "[" + 810 + "]";
```

`800` and `810` is random. now i want to use regex such as `\[(.*?)\]` to capture between brackets with any `\n` into string. this mean is get string like with this :

```
800\n810
```

how to do it and get all numeric data between brackets and have new value for `test` ?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ( "\\[([^]]*)\\]" );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test );
test  = matcher.group();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [**Look around**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as well to get the numbers only that is enclosed inside brackets.

Regex:

```
                         (?<=\[)\d+(?=\])
 Look behind for [ ---------^^^      ^^^------------Look ahead for ]
```

sample code:

```
String test = "hello" + "[" + 800 + "]" + "\n" + "world" + "[" + 810 + "]";

String regex="(?<=\\[)\\d+(?=\\])";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(test);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

output:

```
800
810
```

---

To capture *anything* between brackets use below regex:

```
(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to do it and get all numeric data between brackets

You can use this regex:

```
\[(\d+)\]
```

In Java it will be: `\\[(\\d+)\\]`

To capture **anything between square brackets** use:

```
\[([^]]*)\]
```

**Java Code:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher( test );
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.printf("Group: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Provided you some Java code but I suggest you going through a Java regex tutorial on Oracle site for quick learning as well.

Comment: @jJz: Let me know if you have any further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the javadoc of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Your example would match `"hello8\nworld1"` - tough `"\r?\n"`  might also cover Windows line endings consisting of two character CR aka `\r` and LF aka `\n`-

The backslashes in regex strings that are regex specific, need to be escaped, backslashed, themselves. A much deplored state.

The dot `.` does not match line endings, but there exists an option DOTALL that alters this behaviour. You can set DOT_ALL also with the command string `(?s)` (= single line).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\[(.*?)\\]");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(".....");
//while (m.find() { } // Search in the middle
//if (m.matches()) { } // Match all
if (m.lookingAt()) { // Starting
    String s = m.group(1);
}
```

The eager form with a final question mark `(.*?)` ensures the shortest match, not searching for a further `]` when encountering a `]`.